# Inno setup [icons] section, create desktop icon if it's not there

Tags: inno-setup

we use inno setup to create installer. We use this in our script:

```
[Icons]
Name: {commondesktop}\{#Brand}; Filename: {app}\{#Brand}.exe; Tasks: MYAPP; WorkingDir: {app}
```

to create a desktop. it worked fine. 
But now, we want to only create the desktop shortcut if it's not already there. i guess somehow i have to use the if statement, but seems like "if" is not recognized in the [Icons] section. 
is there a way to do it? 
Thanks
James

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I edited your question to format the code, you can re-edit it to see how it works.  Take a look also at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Check](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptcheck.htm) parameter that tests for the existence of the shortcut file.